# variable insisde a JSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic object property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

considering this json:

```
{
    "items" : [
        { "item_blue" : "10" },
        { "item_green" : "100" },
        { "item_red" : "1000" }
    ]
}
```

is this possible?

```
var item = "item_green";
echo(items.item)    //100
```

Answer (score 2):

No, use

```
items[item]
```

otherwise `items.item` will try to get attribute named item

Answer (score 2):

There is no echo in JS, but you could use bracket notation:

```
var item = "item_green";
console.log(items[item]);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is an invalid JSON.. Need to separate the Objects inside the array with commas

```
var data = {
              "items" : [
                 { "item_blue" : "10" },
                 { "item_green" : "100" },
                 { "item_red" : "1000" }
             ]
          };
```

use **console.log** instead of **echo**

```
var item = "item_green";
console.log(data.items[1][item]);
```

**items.item** would work if your JSON is in this format..

```
var data = {
    "items": {
        "item_blue": "10",
        "item_green": "100",
        "item_red": "1000"
    }
};
```

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/z7FME/)